# can xmlhttpRequest response wait even after onload

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am loading a page through xmlHttpRequest and I am not getting one variable which come into existance after some miliseconds when page loading is done 
so the problem is when xmlHttpRequest sends back the response I do not get that variable in it.
I want it to respond back even after onload.

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", event.url, true);
            xhr.onload = function() { 
                     callback(xhr.responseText); 
                };              
            xhr.onerror = function() { callback(); };

            xhr.followRedirects = true;
            xhr.send();
```

I tried setTimeOut but of no use because may be at that time call is finished

```
    xhr.onload = function() { 
            console.log('wait for response');
            setTimeout(function(){
                 callback(xhr.responseText); 
            },2000);
            };
```

I tried readyStateChange , but no success

```
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            callback(xhr.responseText);
        };
    };
```

by the way, I am trying to load amazon signIn page
and the variable which is missing everytime is hidden Input Field metadata1,
I get all other hidden Input fields in response text , except input field, named "metadat1"

I'll be more than Happy, If anyone can help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ohh Finally I did it,
I din't read any javascript, Instead I just extracted scripts which I received in xhr calls and executed it inside a hidden div, and here it is , I got that variable's value

```
abc(xhr.responseText);

function abc(xhrRes){
 var dynamicElement = document.createElement('div');
 dynamicElement.setAttribute("id", "xhrdiv");
 dynamicElement.setAttribute("style", "display: none;");                                
 dynamicElement.innerHTML = xhrRes;

 document.body.appendChild(dynamicElement);             

 var scr = document.getElementById('xhrdiv').getElementsByTagName("script");

 //5 scripts needed to generate the variable

 for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    eval(scr[i].innerHTML);

    if( i+1 == 5){
           var response = document.getElementById('xhrdiv').innerHTML;
           return response;   //and in this response variable I have every thing I needed from that page which I called through xmlhttp Req 
     }      
 }                          

}
```

---------------------Improved Version-----------------------

Instead of executing script through eval,
keep script content in a file AND Include it, as we normally include the script, that works better.

```
xhrRes = xhr.responseText;

var dynamicElement = document.createElement('div');
dynamicElement.setAttribute("id", "xhrDiv");
dynamicElement.setAttribute("style", "display: none;");                                                         
dynamicElement.innerHTML = xhrRes;

document.body.appendChild(dynamicElement);              

var xhrDiv  = document.getElementById('xhrDiv');    
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
newScript.src = JSfile;
xhrDiv.appendChild(newScript);
```

(it shows the edit is done my anonymous user, :( because I forgot to Login, while editing)

Answer (score -1):

If the data doesn't exist until some time after the page has loaded then, presumably, it is being generated by JavaScript.

If you request the URL with XMLHttpRequest then you will get the source code of that page in the response. You will not get the generated DOM after it has been manipulated by JavaScript.

You need to read the JavaScript on the page you are requesting, work out how it is generating the data you want to read, and then replicate what it does with your own code.

Comment: so, is it not possible to get that data, after javascript has generated it.I think If I could make xmlhttp req wait for few miliseconds more after pageload, then may be  I could get it in request itself, because if I generate it at my end , I will get some other value, as it is being generated randomly, if I generate it at my end, it may prove to be wrong

Comment: "so, is it not possible to get that data, after javascript has generated it." — I told you what you need to do in the last paragraph of the answer.

Comment: "I think If I could make xmlhttp req wait for few miliseconds more after pageload" — You can't because there is no page load. There is just the HTML source code being delivered to the XMLHttpRequest object.

Comment: "if I generate it at my end , I will get some other value, as it is being generated randomly, if I generate it at my end, it may prove to be wrong" — if it is being generated randomly by client side code in the page, then you can't generate the wrong value by generating it in the same way. It is unlikely to be random though, you need to read the JS and figure out what it is actually doing.

Comment: Thank you @Quentin for your response, I'll try to generate it at my end